# R- commutative ring. Show that $N(R)\triangleleft R$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ be a commutative ring. Show that $N(R) \triangleleft R$.

can you help me plese with notation and the proof of this exercise.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $N(R)$?

Comment: What is $\triangleleft$ ?

Comment: @Y'all Hold out on the downvotes... Iuli always poses detailed questions and he even specifically asked about notation. He probably doesn't know what $N(R)$ and $\triangleleft$ mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $N(R)$ is the set of nilpotent elements of $R$, that is $$N(R) = \{ a \in R : \text{there is $n > 0$ such that $a^{n} = 0$} \},$$ and you want to prove it is an ideal of $R$. (This is called the *nilradical* of $R$.)

Clearly $0 \in N(R)$.

If $a^n = 0$ and $b^m=0$, then $(a-b)^{n+m-1} = 0$.

If $a^n = 0$, and $c \in R$, then $(ac)^n = a^n c^n = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. can you recommend me a book with notions of abstract algebra?

Comment: @Iuli: That is an *incredibly* broad question; an appropriate recommendation greatly depends on how much experience you have with proofs in general, and abstract algebra in particular, and moreover what your goals are for the book. For example, one book with notions of abstract algebra is Lang's *Algebra* (GTM 211), which is quite advanced; another book with notions of abstract algebra is Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*, which is more elementary. A good all-around choice is Dummit and Foote.